# Execute an Oracle Schedule-Program through an Oracle Schedule-Job

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I know that in order to schedule any action on a database table i must form a schedule chain, that is, a job (DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB) that links a schedule(DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE) and a program(DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM). But what if i want to accomplish the same task only through a PROGRAM and a linked JOB ? Is it possible ? I have tried and when i check the PROGRAM log it shows me :

```
   RUNS      FAILS
======================
    10        10
```

Which means that the JOB has been executed for 10 times (runs at an interval of 5 secs.) and it has failed for the same number of times.

Following are the codes for concerned JOB and PROGRAM :

```
PROGRAM-CODE :
=================

BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM
(
  program_name         => 'HR.INSERT_PROG'
 ,program_type         => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
 ,program_action       => 'insert into sch_test values (s1.nextval,s2.nextval)'
 ,number_of_arguments  => 0
 ,enabled              => TRUE
 ,comments             => NULL
);
END;


JOB-CODE :
==========

BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
(
   job_name        => 'HR.JOB1'
  ,schedule_name   => 'HR.INSERT_SCH'
  ,program_name    => 'HR.INSERT_PROG'
  ,comments        => NULL
);
END;
```

The concerned table never gets populated. If anyone can tell me, what is it i am doing wrong here? Can this not be achieved without a SCHEDULE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create separate PROGRAM and SCHEDULE, you can put all in one JOB like this:

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
(
   job_name        => 'HR.JOB1'
  ,start_date      => LOCALTIMETAMP
  ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=SECONDLY;INTERVAL=5'
  ,end_date        => NULL
  ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
  ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
  ,job_action      => 'insert into sch_test values (s1.nextval,s2.nextval);'
  ,enabled         => TRUE
);
```

Named schedule objects and named program objects are only useful if you have several of them running in complex combinations and dependencies.

Comment: yes, that has been done and checked and its running all smooth and fine. but just for the sake of curiosity, i want to know if it is possible with a Program and a Job the way i have asked?

And yes, thanks a ton for the answer brother!